# Unable to read Excel sheet on Server Machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am unable to read my Excel sheet on server..when i run this code on Local it works fine...but unable to run this method on server...
 the Error shows "Object Reference not set to an Instance"

```html
  public DataTable GetRead_Excel(string strExcelFile)
        {



            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection OledbCon = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand OledbCmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter OledbDAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt_1 = new DataTable();
            dt_1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt_1.Rows.Add(25);
            OledbCon.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= " + strExcelFile.Trim() + " ;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO\"";

            OledbCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= " + strExcelFile.Trim() + " ;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO\"";


            if (System.IO.File.Exists(strExcelFile.Trim()) == false)
            {
                strErrorCode = "Invalid Excel Data file / File dose not exists";
                return null;
            }

            try
            {
                OledbCon.Open();

                OledbCmd.Connection = OledbCon;
                OledbCmd.CommandTimeout = pSQL_CommandTimeOut;
                OledbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OledbCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
                OledbDAdapter.SelectCommand = OledbCmd;
                OledbDAdapter.Fill(dt_1);
                OledbDAdapter.Dispose();
                OledbCmd.Dispose();
                OledbCon.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strErrorCode = Get_ErrorString(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }

            return dt_1;
        }
```

Comment: Start by determining which object is not being set: use a debugger to step through the code to find where things start going wrong. If you cannot debug on the server, then time to learn how useful logging is.

Comment: Does the event viewer on the server say anything? Can you provide the full text of the error message? Where exactly does the error occur? A gotcha for reading excel files is that sometimes you need the Access Database Engine (or Office itself) installed on the server - which might explain why it works locally but not on the server. Then again, there could be many other reasons for that, like a file directory not existing.

Comment: Does Office is installed on your server ?

Comment: Well i think the object OleDbConnection , OleDbCommand  and OleDbDataAdapter  are unable to read on server..when i remove this object on server it works fine otherwise it wont work

Comment: if the application works without those lines of code, why are they there? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Office is installed on server...actually i wasnt sure which obj not working on server thats y when i remove them then run on server it show no error object reference..which means the error must be these objects which is not working on server side

Comment: does the application do whatever you want it to do when you remove those references? Not "does it run without error", but does it actually do what you want it to? Put in proper logging. If there is no error logging, go to the server's Event Viewer and find the error there. You are not being clear enough.

Comment: well m pretty clear with my debugging..m sure my object are not working on server thats it ...i m reading my excel sheet using OleDbConnection which is unable to read this obj on server